# Custom layout path for fields

Tags: overrides, layout, fields

I have a central library `\libraries\mylib\` containing some models, tables, helpers and stuff all of my components use.
I also have a folder there containing some custom fields i use.

It is simple to tell Joomla where the fields are when caling it from the library:

```
FormHelper::addFieldPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/forms/fields');
```

But Layouts for standard field types like "radio" are getting searched in the component and template folders and have priority.

How can i tell the system to check first priority for alternative field layouts in this folder:

```
\libraries\mylib\layouts\joomla\form\field\
```

Comment: You want core fields to use custom layouts?

Comment: I want a central library with custom field layouts (for standard and custom fields) to be used by multiple extensions which use those fields.